# How to print command output in Ansible when there is a condition?

Tags: ansible

My ansible code looks something like the following. Problem is this only works when my inventory has dev,qa, perf and prod servers. For example, if my inventory has only dev servers then it fails. Is there any way to avoid this failure ?

I tried changing both `cmd_dev_out` and `cmd_qa_out` to `cmd_out` but that did not help either.

```
- name: Execute
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Execute against dev
      shell: some command
      register: cmd_dev_out
      when: ( servers are dev )

    -  debug: msg="{{ cmd_dev_out }}"

    - name: Execute against qa
      shell: some command
      register: cmd_qa_out
      when: ( servers are qa )

    -  debug: msg="{{ cmd_qa_out }}"

    ....... More conditions below .....
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you just use `cmd_out`? You'll need to remove the first `debug` statement and only use the one at the bottom with `cmd_out` and I would expect that to work.

Comment: @Simon I thought the same and attempted those combinations already. The error is quite long but it starts with ```The task includes an option with an undefined variable.```

Comment: Strange. So it seems neither task above is executed then?. Do you get the same error when you define the condition like so: `when: "'dev' in group_names"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be to use a `block` in here to logically group the execution of the `command` and the print of the output of the said command.

Because, if there is no command run, well, obviously you won't get anything as a result.

This is an example using [`block`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html)

```yaml
- name: Execute
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - name: Execute against dev
          shell: 'echo "dev"'
          register: cmd_dev_out

        -  debug: 
             msg: "{{ cmd_dev_out }}"
      when: "'dev' in inventory_hostname"

    - block:
        - name: Execute against qa
          shell: 'echo "qa"'
          register: cmd_qa_out

        -  debug: 
             msg: "{{ cmd_qa_out }}"
      when: "'qa' in inventory_hostname"
```

Mind that this means that the condition `when` is now tied to the `block` and both the `command` and the `debug` will be skipped when the condition is false.

Example of recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************

TASK [Execute against dev] ****************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Execute against qa] *****************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    changed: true
    cmd: echo "qa"
    delta: '0:00:00.002641'
    end: '2023-01-25 20:51:04.049532'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-01-25 20:51:04.046891'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: qa
    stdout_lines:
    - qa
```

---

Another, but maybe less elegant solution would be to use the [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default) Jinja filter on your `command` result in case the `command` was skipped.

```yaml
- name: Execute
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Execute against dev
      shell: 'echo "dev"'
      register: cmd_dev_out
      when: "'dev' in inventory_hostname"

    -  debug: 
         msg: "{{ cmd_dev_out | default('cmd_dev was skipped') }}"
      
    - name: Execute against qa
      shell: 'echo "qa"'
      register: cmd_qa_out
      when: "'qa' in inventory_hostname"

    -  debug: 
         msg: "{{ cmd_qa_out | default('cmd_qa was skipped') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out another solution. Its given below (add the when condition to the debug statement) :

```
- name: Execute
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Execute against dev
      shell: some command
      register: cmd_dev_out
      when: ( servers are dev )

    -  debug: msg="{{ cmd_dev_out }}"
       when: ( servers are dev )

    - name: Execute against qa
      shell: some command
      register: cmd_qa_out
      when: ( servers are qa )

    -  debug: msg="{{ cmd_qa_out }}"
       when: ( servers are qa )
    ....... More conditions below .....
```